# How to set UITextField text that's on the root of a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

To obtain a reference the the UIViewController that's at the root of a navigation controller I do this:

```
UIViewController *root = (UIViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Once I have that reference, how can I set the text in a UITextField that's on that root view?  I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
NSString *str = @"";
[[root txtID] setText:str];
```

Xcode shows the error: "No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'txtID'".

Comment: Clarify "doesn't work" (the most useless words anyone can use in a question). Does it crash? Any errors? Is the text simply not updated?

Comment: Error from Xcode is "No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'txtID'".

Comment: edit and add this error in your question, not only in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
UIViewController *root = (UIViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

You want to reference the actual class for the root controller. Something like:

```
MyRootViewController *root = (MyRootViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Replace `MyRootViewController` with the actual name of the class for your root controller - the one that has the `txtID` property.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom class instead of 'UIViewController' ... And then on the .h file link a @property there.. That should do it...

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one textfield on your root view controller you can foreach all of subviews in your root view and check out is it type of UITextField:

```
    UIViewController *root = (UIViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    for (UIView *v in [root.view subviews])
    {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)v;
            [textField setText:@"My text to set up"];
        }
    }
```

But if you have more TextFields on your root view controllers you should identify it by tag and also compare it before update the text.